# R rbind - numbers of columns of arguments do not match

Tags: r, rstudio, weather, rbind

How can I ignore a data set if some column names don't exist in it?

I have a list of weather data from a stream but I think certain key weather conditions don't exist and therefore I have this error below with `rbind`:

```
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

My code:

```
weatherDf <- data.frame()

for(i in weatherData) {
    # Get the airport code.
    airport <- i$airport

    # Get the date.
    date <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(i$timestamp))/1000, origin="1970-01-01", tz="UTC-1")

    # Get the data in dailysummary only.
    dailySummary <- i$dailysummary

    weatherDf <- rbind(weatherDf, ldply(
        list(dailySummary),
        function(x) c(airport, format(as.Date(date), "%Y-%m-%d"), x[["meanwindspdi"]], x[["meanwdird"]], x[["meantempm"]], x[["humidity"]])
    ))
}
```

So how can I make sure these key conditions below exist in the data:

```
meanwindspdi
meanwdird
meantempm
humidity
```

If **any** of them does not exit, then **ignore** the bunch of them. Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

The content of weatherData is in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdyjh8fo/) (I can't post it here as it is too long and I dunno where is the best place to show the data publicly for R...)

**EDIT 2:**

I get some error when I try to export the data into a txt:

```
> write.table(weatherData,"/home/teelou/Desktop/data/data.txt",sep="\t",row.names=FALSE)
Error in data.frame(date = list(pretty = "January 1, 1970", year = "1970",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

What does it mean? It seems that there are some errors in the data...

**EDIT 3:**

I have exported my entire data in .RData to my google drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_w5RSQMxtRSbjdQYWJMX3pfWXM/view?usp=sharing

If you use RStudio, then you can just import the data.

**EDIT 4:**

```
target_names <- c("meanwindspdi", "meanwdird", "meantempm", "humidity")

# If it has data then loop it.
if (!is.null(weatherData)) {
    # Initialize a data frame.
    weatherDf <- data.frame()

    for(i in weatherData) {
        if (!all(target_names %in% names(i)))
            next

        # Get the airport code.
        airport <- i$airport

        # Get the date.
        date <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(i$timestamp))/1000, origin="1970-01-01", tz="UTC-1")

        # Get the data in dailysummary only.
        dailySummary <- i$dailysummary

        weatherDf <- rbind(weatherDf, ldply(
            list(dailySummary),
            function(x) c(airport, format(as.Date(date), "%Y-%m-%d"), x[["meanwindspdi"]], x[["meanwdird"]], x[["meantempm"]], x[["humidity"]])
        ))
    }

    # Rename column names.
    colnames(weatherDf) <- c("airport", "key_date", "ws", "wd", "tempi", 'humidity')

    # Convert certain columns weatherDf type to numberic.
    columns <-c("ws", "wd", "tempi", "humidity")
    weatherDf[, columns] <- lapply(columns, function(x) as.numeric(weatherDf[[x]]))
}
```

Inspect the `weatherDf`:

```
> View(weatherDf)
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: Try `dput(head(weatherData, 50))` for sharing your data.

Comment: @nrussell I share all my data in jsfiddle. please see my edit above. thanks.

Comment: I do not get any error when I run your code ???

Comment: Do you want to skip the current iteration of the loop if any of the columns is missing in `i`?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein yes. that is what I can think of. unless you have a better idea??

Comment: @G5W that is interesting! dunno why i have the error!! :-(

Comment: @G5W sorry I know why - i gave the wrong data! the data that does not work is too long and I can't even view it on my rstudio console! Any ideas how can I output it with other methods??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `next` to skip the current iteration of the loop and go to the next iteration:

```
target_names <- c("meanwindspdi", "meanwdird", "meantempm", "humidity")

for(i in weatherData) {
  if (!all(target_names %in% names(i)))
    next
  # continue with loop...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it does not give me any data anymore... please see my edit 4. I have all my data exported in edit 3.

Comment: @teelou The target names not present in any of the data frames in `weatherData`. Therefore, all iterations are skipped.